# Wrong axes limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I use the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html).

I believed that x-axes is the interval [0,π] and y-axes [-1,1]. I get this:

[image]

which it is a rectangle [-0.6 , 0.6]×[-0.6 , 0.6].

Do I understand something wrong?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You found a bug in the Matplotlib documentation! :)

You need to replace this line of code:

```
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')
```

with this:

```
ln, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro')
```

That's because the figure has been created with the object oriented approach. Read more about it here: [Object Oriented vs Pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Comment: thanks for your answer! I replaced `ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')` with `ln, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro')` , but the problem appears again...

Comment: restart the kernel and try again. I've tested it on my machine and it works fine. In case it will fail again, make sure to provide the matplotlib version you are using.

Comment: I restarted kernel, but nothing... I 'm using 3.4.3 version of matplotlib.

Comment: Try updating to the latest version. If you are using pip, you can run `pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

Comment: I tried it too! I 'll use a little bit different code.